# Access individual fields from column name (lotusScript)

Tags: lotusscript, lotus

I am trying to write a script that can get a value from a column and change the colour based on what value it is eg. If it is lower than 10, it will be blue and above 10 it will be red. I have created a button that will loop through each record in a report and do this, but that isn't quite what I need.

My problem is that I want to loop through each column individually and check the value, so that the parameters can be different depending on the column header. My current code loops through and can find the field names but not access the fields from them.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which context does this script run? This seems to be a wild mix of LotusScript and JavaScript... Is this for Client or Web?

Comment: This is LotusScript in Lotus approach for client @TorstenLink

Comment: Are you referring to the (very, very) old database product Lotus Approach? I haven't used that since 1995, I think.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz yes, I've been asked to write some scripts using lotusscript in Approach

Comment: Wow. That's a blast from the past. Totally different object model than what most folks are likely to be used to from Notes/Domino.  One thing I'm noticing is that your code does 'forall value in items', but it never references 'value'. Instead, it references items.text on one line, then item.text on another line, and then item.Font.Color a couple of times. That doesn't seem like it can be right to me, but without researching the Approach object model I can't be sure.